# How do I install MComix?

Tags: 11.10

Since short I discovered comics in digital.
It actually is fun reading comics on pc.

Anyway I'm currently using Comix for my comic files (.cbr .cbz etc)
Now I discovered that Comix is discontinued en MComix is taking it's place.
But I don't know how to install it.

When I start MComix without installing it works perfectly
But when I try to install it says something about dependencies or something.
I don't get it what am i supposed to do?

Comment: Can you add some detail to your question about what error it is?

Comment: If you want an alternate comic reader, you may look into https://launchpad.net/~strip-developers. But its in development

Answer (score 3):

Download the file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcomix/).

There was one missing dependency that you'll need to install, it's python-setuptools. You can install it by running the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Then you will have to extract the `mcomix-0.95.tar.bz2` file. Mine downloaded to the Downloads folder, so i ran:

```
tar -xvf ~/Downloads/mcomix-0.95.tar.bz2
```

then:

```
cd ~/Downloads/mcomix-0.95
```

and then run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Once that is finished you should be able to launch it by simply typing `mcomix` in a terminal. Once that opens up,you can visit the unity launcher (if you're using unity), thenright click on the mcomix icon and choose "Keep in Launcher"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this updated Ubuntu ppa to your sources in the Software Center: https://launchpad.net/~blca/+archive/ppa
and download it:
sudo apt-get install mxcomix