# Questions about building new version of OpenJPEG on Ubuntu pc

Tags: libraries, media-library

Is it worth updating to a new version from 2.0.1 in the first place?  
Should I delete the 2.0.1 build to install the new one?  
How is the GitHub versions of the project, like if I wanted to install 2.3.0?  
whats the whole process to build the new version to my pc?  
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woudn't mess with libraries, because you risk breaking the applications that depend on the specific version of that library.

Comment: Too bad the program that I needed it for (MComix v 1.2.1) doesn't say which version of the openJPEG it utilises best. Though I will stick with the openjpeg I'm using because it seems to be fine

Comment: where did you get this programme fom? PPA?

Comment: no, from sourceforge!

Comment: And you compile it yourself?

Comment: Yes I did, I found another question on this site https://askubuntu.com/questions/89663/how-do-i-install-mcomix/129939 and I had problems finding the extracted file so I extracted it from the file manager and that seemed to work. the rest was that I had to get libraries for jpg, tif and other fourmats then I compiled openjpeg using cmake which was all on the same PIL post, (the 2014 pillow update of the answer) https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil#272095

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: Yes it did, yay

Comment: Though I only used it 2 times, one for a .cbz and one for a .pdl

Comment: My dad tried to put windows 10 the laptop (that I installed MComix on) today, he didn't ask me first, and it failed and had to make a new install of Xubuntu again (though I installed it the first time), now I have to reinstall the libraries and other dependencies to install MComix.